# Issue a command to the camera from command line via SSH

Tags: camera, command-line

If I have an SSH app like [SSH Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid), is it possible to issue a command to the camera to take a picture from the command line of a remote SSH client? If so, would you have an example of such a command?

**SSH Droid info**

> SSHDroid is a SSH server implementation for Android.
>   This application will let you connect to your device from a PC and execute commands (like "terminal" and "adb shell") or edit files (through SFTP, WinSCP, Cyberduck, etc...).

The device I'm looking to use it on is ver 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with sshdroid. Termux does have an option to record pictures from the command line.

Comment: Thanks, it looks really, but it's for OS 5.0+. The device I'm looking to use it on is ver 2.3.

Comment: @user126440 2.3 is ancient. And btw, the feature to make screenshots from the command line has only be added with 4.0 AFAIK (same as screen recording only has been added with 5.0).